# Method 'Sort' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm troubleshooting a macro but I'm unable to pinpoint why I keep getting the **following error**:

> Run-time error '2147352560 (80020010)': Method 'Sort' of object
> '_Worksheet' failed

Below is the code I'm currently using. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("aaextractadj").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("aaextractadj").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B80"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("aaextractadj").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AC500")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: you need to add the worksheet parent to each range object.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What does a worksheet parent do? And how do I incorporate that into the range object? Thank you.

Comment: ie: `.SetRange ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("aaextractadj").Range("A1:AC500")` and also with any other `Range()` reference.  Otherwise it is looking to the active sheet and if there is a mismatch between the activesheet and the one being used for the sort it will cause an issue.  One should always attach any range object to the correct parent sheet.

Comment: You shouldn't use implicit `Cells.Select` - it depends on the active workbook during code execution - and this might vary. Most likely there is no worksheet "aaextracted" in the workbook that got activated by `Cells.select`. Use an explicit `set wb = Application.workbooks("YourWorkbooksName.xlsx")` and then work with that. Best thing would be to check if worksheet exists beforehand.